# Escape the order by query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Here is the SQL query run :

```
SELECT * FROM (`news`) WHERE `country` IS NULL AND `region` IS NULL ORDER BY IFNULL(update_date, `create_date)` DESC
```

And you may notice that the create_date has some formatting error, I would like to disable the escape but even I add false after the order_by function it has no effect. How to fix it? Thanks a lot

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('news');
 $this->db->where($data);
 $this->db->order_by('IFNULL(update_date,create_date)', 'DESC', false);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: $this->db->order_by('IFNULL(update_date,create_date)', 'DESC', false); I think it might be because you have false in order by.

Comment: Thanks for reply. both with or without false is return the same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below code:

$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;

$this->db->order_by('IFNULL(update_date,create_date)', 'DESC', false);

$this->db->_protect_identifiers = TRUE;

Answer (score 2):

add this line on top of your db select method.

`$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;`

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, trying to make a sql select with multiplication to work on C.I. 3.10

```
$this->db->order_by("results.result * 1", 'ASC', FALSE);
```

Just adding , FALSE to order_by resolved because $this->db->_protect_identifiers was triggering an error on C.I. 3.10